# Adjusting a Vector3 after a Matrix rotation has occured

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, camera

I'm using C# in XNA to develop a 3D game. I'm implementing a first person camera that can follow the player and when the player turns the camera will also turn.

So far I have the camera following the players co-ordinated fine, the camera's up vector is also fine. The only problem I'm having is that the camera will not rotate as the player rotates. The look at vector doesn't seem to be updating.

```
class Camera
{        
    private Vector3 position;
    private Vector3 target;
    public Matrix viewMatrix;
    public Matrix projectionMatrix;      
    private Vector3 cameraUp;     
    private Matrix cameraRotation;

    public Camera()
    {
        ResetCamera();
    }

    public void ResetCamera()
    {
        Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), 16/9, 1.0f, 500f);
    }

    public void Update(Matrix chasedObjectsWorld, Vector3 mdlPos, float mdlRotation)
    {
        UpdateViewMatrix(chasedObjectsWorld, mdlPos, mdlRotation);  
    }


    private void UpdateViewMatrix(Matrix chasedObjectsWorld, Vector3 mdlPos, float mdlRotation)
    {           
        cameraRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY(mdlRotation);

        position = new Vector3(mdlPos.X,mdlPos.Y,mdlPos.Z);
        cameraUp = new Vector3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
        target = cameraRotation.Forward;

        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, target, cameraUp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `CreateLookAt` is the point you wish the camera to look at. In your current code you take the forward vector from a rotation matrix with no translation. Your look at point (`target`) is relative to the origin `(0,0,0)` but your camera position is at `position`. Try putting `position + target` as the second argument instead of just `target`.